# Paths property of module object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

When I print any module's `module` object to the console, I get output such as the following:

```
{ id: '.',
  exports: {},
  parent: null,
  filename: '/Users/myname/audiooutput/bin/audiomodule.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: [...], // array of module objects, omitted for brevity
  paths: // what is this?
   [ '/Users/myname/audiooutput/bin/node_modules',
     '/Users/myname/audiooutput/node_modules',
     '/Users/myname/node_modules',
     '/Users/node_modules',
     '/node_modules' ] }
```

Here I see the usual `module` properties listed in the [Node.js Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object): `id`, `exports`, `parent`, `filename`, `loaded`, and `children`.

However, there is a final property, `paths`, an array. The elements of the array don't refer to actual directories. They seem meaningless. So, my question is: what is the purpose/use of the paths property of `module` objects, and why isn't it listed int the Node.js Documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure those paths don't exist?

Comment: @RUJordan I'm sure. Everything is valid expect for the final '/node_modules' folder in each path. That's what doesn't exist. For example, '/Users/myname/audiooutput/bin' is a valid directory, but there is no 'node_modules' folder in it.

Comment: @RUJordan The second path is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the paths where `require` will look for the modules you require from this file:

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders.